# Будильник на C

Tags: c

Задача:

`Разработать программу, которая имитирует работу электронного будильника программа должна обеспечить возможность указать время, когда сигнал тревоги и период действия сигнала. разрешить указание нескольких точек зрения сигналов. применять спикер управления получать звуковой сигнал.`

Нужно все это реализовать на чистом "С" в консоле. Увы я как пэхопешник не могу осуществить эту задачу и не мне нужно ее решение. Если есть добрые люди которые не напишут эту программу вместо меня, а хотя бы дадут понятия реализации, буду премного благодарен.

Comment: Для получения *биип*  выводите код 07. 

На Си, например

    putchar(07);

если стандартный вывод "будильника" связан с окном консоли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз Вы даже не указали, под какую ось и что Вы готовы использовать, опишу самый простой (хотя и наивный вариант).

Для начала понадобится найти функцию, которая будет получать текущее время и пару функций для перевода строки с временем в этот формат и назад. Эти функции нужно будет найти.

Сам код для будильника будет просто. Заводите цикл, который будет проверять текущее время и сравнивать с заданным. Если оно меньше - ждем дальше (понадобится sleep или аналоги), нет -  выводим сообщение. Что бы цикл не дергался часто - sleep можно выставлять на разные промежутки, что бы он завершался за пару минут до нужного срабатывания, а потом дергать с интервалом в 20 секунд.

Второй вариант - использовать функции типа select, которые могут заменить sleep.

Третий вариант - использовать "будильники" операционной системы. В Linux это [alarm](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=alarm&category=2&russian=0).